# Breadth first search not working 100%

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, breadth-first-search

working on doing a bfs for an adjacency matrix which is buil as an array of linked lists.

Here is my bfs method, receives the array of linked lists and starting location:

```
public static int bfs(List<Integer>[] smallWorld, int start){


    int distance = 0;
    int size = smallWorld.length;

    //for each location in smallWorld do a bfs to every other location      
    int u;
    int white = 0, grey = 1, black = 2;
    int [] color, d, pie;
    Queue <Integer> q = new <Integer> LinkedList();

    color = new int [size];
    d = new int [size];
    pie = new int [size];

    for( int x = 0; x < size; x++){
        color[x] = white;
        d[x] = -1;
        pie[x] = -1;
    }

    color[start] = grey;
    d[start] = 0;
    pie[start] = -1;
    q.addAll(smallWorld[start]);        //enqueue the adjacent items
    while(!q.isEmpty()){
        u = q.remove();
        for(int v = 0; v < smallWorld[u].size(); v++){      //for every vertex u is adjacent to
            if(color[v] == white){
                color[v] = grey;
                d[v] = d[u] + 1;
                pie[v] = u;
                q.addAll(smallWorld[v]);
            }
        }
        color[u] = black;
    }

    int x = 0;
    while(d[x] != -1){
        distance = distance + d[x];
        x++;
    }
```

Really smallWorld is of length 500, but for testing purposes im just doing a bfs on the first index in the array. (Ya know bfs is supposed to give back the shortest possible path between 2 indexes in the array). Mine has been running for about 14 min now and im not sure why, i mean i assume its because the !isEmpty() but that only adds stuff to the queue if its white so sooner or later that has to run out.

**EDITED. FIGURED OUT ENDLESS LOOP PROBLEM BUT BFS METHOD STILL NOT 100%**

any ideas why it isnt working? I mean i followed the algorithm to the T, but the algorithm generally isnt referring to an array of linked lists.

Any ideas to solve this problem

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? Or just printing sysouts atleast?

Comment: yea i was doing printouts but figured out why it was running forever. but my bfs method still doesnt work, also cant figure that out. I followed the algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

The problem could be in this while loop.  You are not incrementing x.

```
int x = 0;
while(d[x] != -1){
    distance = distance + d[x];
}
```

Comment: haha yeah that was it but turns out my BFS method still needs some work too! thanks for pointing that one out!